# Need help with Binary Columns

Tags: binary

I have to query a column containing a Binary column with data like this ®â{Õ■K!Eòû▓♫;#§ø.

How can i query this colmn..if I wanted something like:

SELECT Name 
FROM   Users
WHERE ID = ®â{Õ■K!Eòû▓♫;#§ø

THanks

Comment: SQL Server 2005/08? Oracle? SQLite? Any other DB?

Comment: Also, are you running the query from an SQL client or from code? If client, which client? If code, what language and driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Several RDBMS (I thinks at least MySQL ans MS SQL Server) use the `0x…………` notation where you put `0x` + your binary bytes in hexadecimal pairs, e.g. `SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE ID = 0x402041` matches id `'@ A'`.

PostGreSQL uses [escaping and the `bytea` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/datatype-binary.html).

I've also read something about the format `X'402041'`.

This is depedent on your SQL flavour, you should check the corresponding documentation for "binary litterals" or "binary strings".